# How do you automatically add text from a file?

Tags: premiere

I recently created a video which has associated data. Like position, altitude, direction in another file. I know the time offsets for each event and would like to put this data into the video as text. Is there a way without changing the video text areas manually?

Thanks in advance,

Gregg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dashware](http://www.dashware.net/) is an (free) app which does just this.

> Telemetry Data Overlay on your Videos
>
> Easily display GPS, vehicle, physiology, and environment data from
> smartphones and dedicated loggers.

Besides CSV text files, it imports data from many formats. You don't have to render the final composited video from Dashware. You can export a synchronised chroma-key ready video of the overlay for import into your video editor.

Comment: This looks exactly right, but I will be checking it out tomorrow. I will probably be back to accept your answer shortly, unless something even cooler comes up, but this is pretty awesome.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I am trying todo. Thank you for your answer!